# Find what row a given number exists in within a binary heap tree.

Tags: binary

If I have a binary heap tree like so:

```
            1
     2,             3
 4,     5,      6,      7
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
16 ... 31
32 ... 63
64 ... 127
```

I would say 5 is in row 3, and 115 is in row 7.

I'm sure the equation is stupid simple like "duh, find the square root."  But I'm not seeing it.

So how do I determine which row in the heap a given number is in.

Comment: I don't find 115

Comment: 115 is in row 7.  I have elipses to describe continuing the pattern.  It's between 64 and 127.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ok, gotcha.

number $n$ is going to be in the following level:

$\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor +1$

Here is a c++ function for it:

```
int findfloor(int x){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0,j=1; 2*j <= x; i++,j*=2){}
    return(i+1);
}
```

Comment: I like that the integer returns 7 where n is 115.  But the full result is 7.8454900509443757.  While that works, shouldn't I be scared that numbers waaaaay further down might be incorrect?  (Possibly too high?) Or is that just a result of it not being the first number in row 7.

Comment: haha, no. the first number on each level is always going to give you the exact value

Comment: Right, makes sense.  Thank you for the super fast and awesome answer.

Comment: Sure, I added a c++ function that finds the floor, just be careful your number is an int under 2^62